# How to change horizontal mac style dock menu to vertical orientation?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, vertical-alignment, dock

I have got this jQuery plugin that shows mac style dock horizontally like this :
[Demo here](http://www.ndesign-studio.com/demo/css-dock-menu/css-dock.html)

I have tried changing it's css to make it vertical on left side of page but there seems to be some issue.

Can anyone help me on this?

MY HTML:

```
<div class="dock" id="dock2">
<div class="dock-container2"><nav id="main-nav">

 <li> <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Quotes</span><img src="images/quote-icon.png" alt="home" /></a> </li>
 <li> <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Jokes</span><img src="images/joke.png"          alt="contact" /></a> </li>
  <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Facts</span><img src="images/fact.png" alt="portfolio" /></a> 
  <a class="dock-item2" href="#"><span>Health</span><img src="images/heart3.png"             alt="portfolio" /></a> 

 </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dock2 {
width: 100%;
bottom: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: -500px;


}
.dock-container2 {
position: absolute;
height: 15px;
background: url(images/dock-bg.gif);
padding-left: 20px;

}
a.dock-item2 {
display: block; 
font: bold 30px Goudy Stout, Goudy Stout, Goudy Stout;
width: 60px; 
color: #000; 
bottom: 0px; 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
.dock-item2 span {
display: none;
padding-left: 20px;

}
.dock-item2 img {
border: none; 
margin: 5px 10px 0px; 
width: 100%; 
}

#zoom
{
position:absolute;
top:200px;

}
#zoom span {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 25px;
display: block;
transition: font-size .2s;
-moz-transition: font-size .2s;
-webkit-transition: font-size .2s;
}

#zoom span:hover {
font-size: 50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#dock2').Fisheye(
            {
                maxWidth: 80,
                items: 'a',
                itemsText: 'span',
                container: '.dock-container2',
                itemWidth: 70,
                proximity: 150,
                alignment : 'right',
                valign: 'bottom',
                halign : 'center'
            }
        )
    }

);

</script>
```

Comment: I can make that with pure CSS http://jsfiddle.net/Xf8Wt/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for the fiddle. Let me try that css on my dock and let me see if it works.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did the same as your fiddle, it is zooming up the text vertically aligned. but if I place img in span , it does not zoom up the images. it only zooms text.

Comment: @Faizan Because I am transitioning the font size, you need to transition height and width if you are using images

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have added my code in question, can you point out exactly where do I need to change to get the dock vertical ?

Comment: @Faizan Base Idea, now you can wrap the images in fixed height width container to avoid push downs :) http://jsfiddle.net/Xf8Wt/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30176/discussion-between-faizan-and-mr-alien)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks a lot for the favor. One last thing, using your approach everything is fine except that it could be a bit more smoother. just like the one in demo.
Anyway, just another thought is it really hard to change that plugin in someway to behave vertically.

Comment: @Faizan 1 is smoothness and other is compatibility but the best is, it's light, its quick

Comment: Remember that it doesn't work in earlier versions of IE (< IE10) - not sure if it matters though